# Find the largest real $k$ such that: $(a+b+c)^2(ab+bc+ca)\geq k(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2)$

Tags: inequality, polynomials, optimization, symmetric-polynomials, muirhead-inequality

> Find the largest real $k$ such that for every non negative real numbers $a,b,c$ : $$(a+b+c)^2(ab+bc+ca)\geq k(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2)$$

I expanded the LHS but the problem got more complicated and no progress...

Comment: My guess is that you first set $a=b=c$ and find the values of $k$ for which the inequality holds, and then try to prove the same $k$ is good for arbitrary $a,b,c$.

Comment: @user8734617 This way we get : $k\leq 9$,but I feel lower upper bounds for $k$ are possible

Comment: Since we're just trying a few different cases to get a reasonable bound on $k$, you should try with $a = 1, b = c = 0$ and $a = b = 1, c = 0$ as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $c=0$ and $a=b=1$ we obtain $4\geq k$.

We'll prove that $4$ is a maximal value.

Indeed, by Muirhead we obtain:

$$(a+b+c)^2(ab+ac+bc)=\sum_{cyc}(a^2+2ab)\sum_{cyc}ab=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}(a^3b+a^3c+a^2bc+2a^2b^2+4a^2bc)=\sum_{cyc}(a^3b+a^3c+2a^2b^2+5a^2bc)\geq$$
$$\geq\sum_{cyc}(4a^2b^2+5a^2bc)\geq4(a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2)$$ and we are done!

Comment: Is it now necessarily proved that 4 is the least upper bound for $k$?

Comment: The minimal value does not exist because it's true for all $k\leq0$.